# Samsung Galaxy S4 NFC Stopped Detecting Mifare Ultralight C Tags

Tags: nfc, galaxy, mifare

At some point in the last few months my UK Galaxy S4 (on 3 network but unlocked) I9505 has stopped detecting a specific type of NFC tag. I suspect it has been knocked out by an update by Samsung as I have changed batteries with a brand new one to no avail.

I went into Carphone warehouse and got them to try the Mifare Ultralight C tags (which did work for me for many months) on other phones. Curiously their staff owned S4s did NOT detect the tag either however the brand new in box phones did! This is when I swapped the battery from a working one into my phone to no avail.

I factory reset my phone but still the tags were not detected. Mifare Classic 1K tags WERE detected but correctly showed the 'tag not supported' message due to the Broadcom chipset in the S4 (The S3 has the NXP chipset and does support the Classic 1K). I used my Google Nexus 7 to check and identify the tags were working and of the correct type.

I went to the Samsung website and found that they indeed confirm that Ultralight C tags ARE supported.

Goto Samsung website / support / mobile phone / choose S4 / Troubleshooting / FAQ ....and search for NFC then click the FAQ link marked "[897701] Why does my Galaxy S4 fail to recognise some NFC tags that the Galaxy S3 recognises?"

It States

> "Examples of NFC tags that the Galaxy S4 supports include: NFC Forum
>   type 1 - 4, Mifare DesFire, Mifare UltraLight, and Mifare UltraLight
>   C.
>
> Examples of NFC tags that the Galaxy S4 does not support include: the
>   Mifare Classic series (Mifare Classic 1K, 3K, Mifare Mini, Mifare Plus
>   2K and Mifare Plus 4K)."

I phoned Samsung UK customer technical support who said it was news to them and they will escalate it and get back to me. They said factory resetting the phone wont remove the updates so suggested I re-flash my phone but couldn't tell me how to do it!

SO MY QUESTIONS ARE:-

1. Is anyone else having this problem? Do you know why this is
   happening? Is there a workaround/fix that doesnt cripple me to old
   firmware? What is the best way for me to change the ROMs on this
   model? (Details below)

About My Phone....

Model: GT-I9505
Android Version: 4.2.2
Baseband Version: I9505XXUDMH8
Kernel Version: 3.4.0-1220396
Build number: JDQ39.I9505XXUDMH8
SELinux status: Enforcing
Secure Boot Status: Type:Samsung

AP: I9505XXUDMH8
CP: I9505XXUDMH8
CSC: I9505OXXUDMHA

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks
Dean

Answer (score 2):

The same happened to me today, after a Samsung upgrade that turned on the (famous/infamous) "knox" (version I9505XXUDMH6 for me). This is a set of additional protection Samsung uses to prevent ROM modifications, rooting etc.
Among them, SELinux goes from permissive to enforcing.
I see you have it too; my suspect is that this upgrade broke something in the NFC section. My colleague with the same device (GT-9505) but an older sotck ROM (still a 4.2.2, but not upgraded since the phone is just out of the box, with SELinux permissive) works, another colleague with the same device and Cyogenmod (4.3)  works too.

In my case, the problem is with Desfire cards, which fail authentication with 0x67 0x00 (length error). Again, the exact same cards and apps work on other devices.

Comment: I assume you posted issue [#61605](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61605) on the Android bug tracker, right? Could your issue be related to part 1 of [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19589534/android-nfc-communication-with-mifare-desfire-ev1/19593349)? I.e. that you send a native DESFire command while the card has already been activated for ISO 7816-4 framing?

Comment: @MichaelRoland yes, I posted that issue. I have seen also the SO question you are pointing to, but it does not seem my problem. My code works on every other device (S2, S3, Nexus, Nexus S, Nexus 7 and Nexus 4), and on every S4 I tested which does not have the Knox update. Also, it happens later in the chains of commands for me (I successfully select the application using a native command, and it fails at the second step - authentication)

Comment: Oh, and it worked on the same device before the update, but stopped working after the update. All in all, it really seems it is a firmware/kernel issue.

Comment: That's really odd. I suspected that maybe the update contained some changes in the tag activation that lead to the tags not being properly reset before passing on to the app. However, as you successfully send native commands and only later receive the error code something must go really wrong on the Android (or libnfc-nci) side. Though I really wonder what causes the card to suddenly change to ISO 7816-4 framing in the middle of the communication. Or is the `67 00` error code generated on the reader side?

Comment: For debugging that issue, could you try to continue using ISO wrapped native commands as soon as you receive the `67 00` error code? It would be interesting if that worked...

Comment: Btw. as I mentioned in the other post, in my opinion it is legal for the Android device to activate the card in ISO 7816-4 framing and not reset the card before passing it on to the app. However, it would certainly be a bug if that behavior was not consistent for one particular device model or if it changed during communication.

Comment: Yes, I was already thinking about it after reading your post.. I will try to send the "authenticate" in ISO framing..
Still, it is very strange that it changes from Native to ISO in the middle of a communication. I'll let you know!

Comment: Ok, really strange but.. that did it! Well, almost.. Wrapping the commands as soon as I get 0x67 0x00 does produce meaningful answers, but I get a 0x91 0x40 (no key), as if the select command got "forgotten". So I switched all my commands to ISO from the beginning and that works. It is as if the card gets reset after the first command is issued... Definitely a strange behaviour, but if everything works in ISO mode on all our devices, I will be happy :)

Comment: That's what I expected. So we are one step closer to what actually happens. Seems as if Android is accessing the DESFire card (maybe trying to read NDEF data) **after** passing it to the app. This certainly is an Android bug. So I guess it would be interesting if the same happens if the DESFire card contained the NDEF tag application. And, particularly, if that application is in selected state after the `67 00` error occured.

Comment: I do not have a desfire card NDEF data, but I could write one and test..How could I check if the NDEF application is "selected"? Anyway, right now I switched all the commands in my application to ISO, and it works. Thank you very much for pointing me in that direction! Maybe it is just safer to use ISO commands and stop. Although I will have to retest on all our devices :) :(

Comment: Under the assumption that you use a DESFire EV1 card and NXP's TagWriter to write the NDEF data: If the NDEF tag application is selected, you should be able to read a standard data file with file ID 01 (accessible in plain text mode without MAC). This file should contain at least 15 bytes (capability container, in the form of `xxxx  20  003B  0034  04 06 E104 xxxx 00 00`).

Answer (score 1):

Mifare Ultralight tags are among the most reliable to read tags.

If this tag technology stopped working from one day to another it looks like a hardware failure of the NFC controller to me. There is a lot of firmware inside the NFC controller, maybe you've experienced some bit-rot that made detecting Mifare Ultralights impossible.

Answer (score 0):

I work in the NFC field and recently upgraded my S3 to the S4 in the hope of demonstrating NFC with Samsung's Flagship handset. Unfortunately I hit a brick wall too when it came to some tags, and in particular the Type 3 tag, which I use as my main product. There is definitely a problem with the communication between the Broadcom Chipset and the Type 3 tag supplied by Sony. It appears that the Nexus is also having problems communicating with the Type 3 tag. I am unsure as to how Samsung propose to resolve this matter due to the number of handsets it involves, but for now it sure is causing a problem. One of the reasons I believe this problem is occurring is because the antenna for the Broadcom Chipset is situated on the battery and not in the handset itself? Maybe if a new battery is manufactured with a different antenna this may help resolve the issue? Then anyone experiencing the problem will have the option of replacing the battery and Samsung would then not have to be too concerned about resolving this issue with every S4 supplied. Luckily for now, not every consumer requires the use of NFC, but hopefully by the time NFC becomes mainstream, samsung would have a more appropriate solution if not a new handset?