# Difference/usage between enableReaderMode and enableForegroundDispatch

Tags: android, nfc

I understand you can use two methods to catch a tag in your foreground activity:

- **enableForegroundDispatch** which give priority to your activity. It will lauch a new intent or creates a new activity, depending on the activity's launchmode.
- **enableReaderMode** where you can define a `ReaderCallback`.  The tag will be send to the `ReaderCallback` and you will be able to catch the tag in your activity with `onTagDiscovered`.

What's the difference between there two methods? In what case would you use one above the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One case is explained in the answer [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20347132/how-mature-is-the-android-nfc-isodep-support): As they explain there, you would use **enableReaderMode** for phones having Broadcom NFC chipsets. This method allows you to use the parameter [EXTRA_READER_PRESENCE_CHECK_DELAY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html#EXTRA_READER_PRESENCE_CHECK_DELAY) which provides a workaround.

Other than that, you have the cases explained in the Android API documentation: when you need to limit your application to the NFC reader mode, not peer-to-peer or card emulation.